# I am facing problems in Conditional Statements With input Fields Of bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, conditional-statements

Here Is My Logic:
It Didn't Work :(

```
    function ShowDropMenu(){
        var numfiled = document.getElementById('numpeple'); //I Want Whenever Someone Enters a Number In Input Field It Should Display The Dropdown Menu?
        if (numfiled < 0 ) {
            document.getElementById('dropmock').style.display="block"
        }
        else{
            alert('Please Add Atleast 1 Or More People to go ahead)
        }
    }
```

I Don't Know What's Went Wrong?

Comment: `document.getElementById()` returns a reference to a DOM element, or it returns `null` if no such element is found. Comparing that to 0 does not make sense; you may have meant to access the `.value` property of the element (assuming it's an `<input>` element), or perhaps something else; it's not clear from what you posted.

Comment: Also do you really want the number to be *less than* zero?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`numfiled` is an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), so comparing it with a number won't do anything meaningful.

You want the *value* of the `Element`.  *Additionally*, since the value is always a string, you want to parse it as a number.  For example:

```
var numfiled = parseInt(document.getElementById('numpeple').value);
```

---

*Note: This assumes `#numpeple` refers to an `<input>` element, inferred from the comment in the code: "Someone Enters a Number In Input Field"*